# ECHO a blank line for every 2 lines

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to get info about services in batch file. Typing `sc query | findstr "SERVICE_NAME DISPLAY_NAME"` and getting output like that:

`SERVICE_NAME: Appinfo
DISPLAY_NAME: Uygulama Bilgileri
SERVICE_NAME: AudioEndpointBuilder
DISPLAY_NAME: Windows Ses Bitiş Noktası Oluşturucu
SERVICE_NAME: Audiosrv
DISPLAY_NAME: Windows Ses
SERVICE_NAME: bdredline
DISPLAY_NAME: Bitdefender RedLine Service
SERVICE_NAME: BFE`

I want to echo a blank line for every 2 lines. Like that:

`SERVICE_NAME: Appinfo
DISPLAY_NAME: Uygulama Bilgileri`

`SERVICE_NAME: AudioEndpointBuilder
DISPLAY_NAME: Windows Ses Bitiş Noktası Oluşturucu`

How can I do that? BTW English isn't my first language and I can call myself a noob. So please explain it with basic words.

Comment: I don't know how to use some commands in that topic. So, can you explain how can I do that?

Comment: @HolyPokerFace If you have a question about an answer, it is better to comment the answer rather than posting a new question.

Comment: @HolyPokerFace Albeit the title of the referenced Q&A matches, the `for /f` used there is quite special. I added a more universal answer there.